# How do I find out if a storage unit is HDD or SSD?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ssd, device-manager

I sit behind a Windows computer. I see it has several disks.

Without breaching the case, how can I find out which ones are SSD and which ones are HDD, using software?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can test only in Win 10 pro at the moment.

PowerShell

```
PS> Get-PhysicalDisk | Select-Object DeviceId,MediaType

DeviceId MediaType
-------- ---------
1        SSD
0        HDD
```

Answer (score 3):

In theory you can use WMIC (`wmic diskdrive get caption` + googling the models)  to do this *but* [diskovery](https://diskovery.io/) is what I use for this. Its portable and in beta but its the cleanest solution I know of, and it does things like identify RAID arrays and so on

[image]

Over by the left is a listing of what the storage devices are, and their "internal" device names for windows. Below that, you can match up what the storage devices and volumes are.

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness, another one tool I usually using - [HWinfo](https://www.hwinfo.com/) for such tasks. It is also doesn't requiring installation and providing more technical information about computer.

[image: SSD_detection]

Comment: I'm pretty sure these things use WMI internally to detect these. I've never worked out what *command* it uses for that tho.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek So, maybe I should have included an additional criterion of "without using extraneous software" in my question. Well... live and learn, although if someone did add an answer complying with that criterion, I'll be sure to move the tick mark.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek `wmic diskdrive get caption, mediatype` but only works on Windows 8.1+

Comment: Lists both drive types as "fixed" Short of parsing the model names, I can't really find any "standard" method for this. Some people even rely on speed tests.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I'm pretty sure these tools don't use WMI to distinguish HDD vs SSD. It looks like reliable way to get such info is to obtain word 217(Rotation rate) and 169(Data Set Management Support or basically TRIM support) and probably 231(SSD life left) over ATA8-ACS to conclude if it is SSD or not. That's I think a reason why both of these tools requiring admin's permission to be able to use DeviceIoControl(IOCTL_ATA_****) API.

Comment: @DavidPostill I had to remove the space character between "," and "mediatype", but it only reports "fixed hard disk media".

Comment: ah! Maybe device hardware id - my NVMe drive reads SCSI\DISK&VEN_NVME&PROD_... Will check tommorrow.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek If you would find something let us know please, I tried to debug it a few years ago in attempt to figure out how Win7 knows that it runs on SSD but swamped in countless API calls